# What should we prefer in a good programming practice ? @Produces("application/json") or @Produces(MediaType.APPICATION_JSON)?

Tags: java, json

Regarding REST Web Service.

- `@Produces("application/json")` and
- `@Produces(MediaType.APPICATION_JSON)`

Both work the same way, but the 2nd one needs an mandatory import i.e. `import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType`, which leads to 1 extra import in my project, while the 1st one does not.
If the 1st one does the trick why do we even refer the second?
The 2nd one increases the count of imports & the imports certainly affect performance and execution don't they?

Comment: Thank you Ibrahim...just threw the qun. in hurry. ty though.

Answer (score 3):

For your compiled class there is no difference:
 
Since `javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` is a static final String constant your compiled class will have no reference to the `MediaType` class but simply contain the String as constant in its constant pool.

But there is a small advantage in using the constant in your source code since it prevents typos.

Comment: I see...as u said..."MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON" Or simply specifying a string as "application/json" won't make a huge diff.
Just to avoid the typos. Then using the MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON" is a good programming practice I learn...right.?

Comment: I'll follow it now on-wards. Thank you for your concern.